# Struggling to install pyobject-1.0

Tags: python-3.x, pip, pyobject

I have developed some python code on Windows 3.9.0 environment. I run `pip freeze prog.py > requirements.txt`. I then tried to re-create a similar environment on my RaspberryPi running Python v3.7.3.
However, `sudo pip install -r requirements.txt` is always failing to install the `pyobject`.

I manually tried to explicitly install this specific module, but it is continually failing.

```sh
pi@raspberrypi:~/operational_report $ sudo pip install pyobject
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
Collecting pyobject
  Using cached pyobject-1.0.tar.gz (12 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-f845qmhj/pyobject_5cd636e5023149cdad8facedb280eced/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-f845qmhj/pyobject_5cd636e5023149cdad8facedb280eced/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-dxk1_umj
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-f845qmhj/pyobject_5cd636e5023149cdad8facedb280eced/
    Complete output (7 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-f845qmhj/pyobject_5cd636e5023149cdad8facedb280eced/setup.py", line 8, in <module>
        long_desc=open("README.rst").read()
      File "/usr/lib/python3.7/codecs.py", line 322, in decode
        (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
    UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb8 in position 13: invalid start byte
    ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/bb/e2/2fc82c012dbcbb3f817e3469076d801597221e031c3055cc0d53d199a6c8/pyobject-1.0.tar.gz#sha256=365215501067aff41db991561f98f0d28c410fbc870e531615c07b7168f36b6a (from https://pypi.org/simple/pyobject/). Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyobject
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pyobject
```

Do you have any advice?

Comment: First, pyobject has two versions 1.0 and 1.1. Is there a reason you're using 1.0 only? Second, I tried to look at the pypi project page (https://pypi.org/project/pyobject/) and it does not say which versions of python it is compatible with. Given that it was developed in 2020, it's likely that they did not test it for 3.7.x.

Comment: Transpires that this module was not required in the program - so that problem has effectively "gone away"!